# Time series data merge nearest right dataset has multiple same values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. The first is like a log while the second is like inputs. I want to combine this log and inputs based on their time columns.

I tried using `merge_asof` but it only takes one input into the input dateframe.

Here is an example. Dataframe Log Times, `log`:

```
    STARTTIME_Log
2020-05-28 21:57:27.000000  
2020-05-28 06:35:20.000000  
2020-05-28 19:51:39.000000  
2020-05-28 20:43:23.000000
```

DataFrame İnput Times and Values, `input`:

```
    IO_Time             IOName  value
2020-05-28 21:57:35.037    A    79.65
2020-05-28 21:57:35.037    B    33.33
2020-05-28 06:35:22.037    A    27.53
2020-05-28 06:35:22.037    B    6.23
2020-05-28 09:30:20.037    A    43.50
2020-05-28 09:30:20.037    B    15.23
2020-05-28 19:51:40.037    A    100.00
2020-05-28 19:51:40.037    B    12.52
2020-05-28 20:43:25.037    A    56.43
2020-05-28 20:43:25.037    B    2.67
2020-05-28 22:32:56.037    A    23.45
2020-05-28 22:32:56.037    B    3.55
```

Expected Output:

```
 STARTTIME_Log               IOName     value
2020-05-28 21:57:27.000000      A       79.65
2020-05-28 21:57:27.000000      B       33.33
2020-05-28 06:35:20.000000      A       27.53
2020-05-28 06:35:20.000000      B       6.23
2020-05-28 19:51:39.000000      A       100.00
2020-05-28 19:51:39.000000      B       12.52
2020-05-28 20:43:23.000000      A       56.43
2020-05-28 20:43:23.000000      B       2.67
```

The output merges the `log` and `input` dataframes in the nearest time.
The merge is done on `STARTTIME_Log` for the `log` dataframe and `IO_Time` on `input`.
If there is too large a difference then the rows are dropped.

How can I do that?

Comment: An explanation of your output will be great.

Comment: Please add your current code, current output and explain how is it meant to merge on times that are not equal, as start time have never equal values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that the `IO_Time` and `STARTTIME_Log` columns are of datetime type and are sorted (required to use `merge_asof`:

```
log['STARTTIME_Log'] = pd.to_datetime(log['STARTTIME_Log'])
input['IO_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(input['IO_Time'])

log = log.sort_values('STARTTIME_Log')
input = input.sort_values('IO_Time')
```

Now, use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `input` as the left dataframe and `log` as the right. Note that you need to specify an acceptable tolerance value (I set it to 10 seconds here):

```
tol = pd.Timedelta('10s')

df = pd.merge_asof(input, log, left_on='IO_Time', right_on='STARTTIME_Log', tolerance=tol, direction='nearest')
df = df.dropna(subset=['STARTTIME_Log']).drop(columns='IO_Time')
```

Afterwards, the rows that don't have a match in `log` are dropped and the `IO_Time` column is removed.

Result:

```
   IOName    value        STARTTIME_Log
0       A    27.53  2020-05-28 06:35:20
1       B     6.23  2020-05-28 06:35:20
4       A   100.00  2020-05-28 19:51:39
5       B    12.52  2020-05-28 19:51:39
6       A    56.43  2020-05-28 20:43:23
7       B     2.67  2020-05-28 20:43:23
8       A    79.65  2020-05-28 21:57:27
9       B    33.33  2020-05-28 21:57:27
```